# Why is my recursion not working Selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, recursion

I'm new to Selenium, I'm trying to crawl into a website to index things, but my recursion is only giving me the first element of each categories :

```py
def crawl_table(driver, max_depths) : 
    
    liste_lien = driver.find_elements(By .TAG_NAME, 'table')
    if (liste_lien == "" or max_depths == 0): 
        return get_fiche(driver)
    else :
        for element in liste_lien : 
            print(element.text)
            lien = element.find_element(By .TAG_NAME, 'a')
            subdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe")
            subdriver.get(lien.get_attribute('href'))
            crawl_table(subdriver, max_depths - 1)
```

It works correctly in a first place, but when it ends up on a page to index it goes back to the root of the recursion.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does each table in liste_lien contain just one link?

Comment: I'm going to update my post, links of the table were stored in only one block, so find_element function was just taking the first link at the top of the table

Answer (score 0):

Actually the link were stored in one bloc so *find_element* was taking the element at the top and was done, I used the *find_elements* function and went through the links to do the recursion :

```py
def crawl_table(driver, max_depths) : 
    liste_lien = driver.find_elements(By .TAG_NAME, 'table')
    if (liste_lien == "" or max_depths == 0): 
        return get_fiche(driver)
    else :
        for element in liste_lien : 
            lien = element.find_elements(By .TAG_NAME, 'a')
            for l in lien : 
                subdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe")
                subdriver.get(l.get_attribute('href'))
                crawl_table(subdriver, max_depths - 1)
```